# jQuery use off() with stored object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I set a click event to elements using `$(document).on("click", ".card" , flipCard);` When the element is clicked I store it in a variable to latter use.

```
function flipCard () {
    
    $(this).addClass('flip');
    if (!hasFlippedCard) {
        firstCard = this;

        return;
    } 
    
    secondCard = this;
    checkForMatch();
}
```

I want to remove the click latter but i am not sure how to remove it from `firstCard` I think I might use .map() but have not seen an example of how I might use in this context.

I want to do something like this `$('element').off("click");`

This does not work

```
function cardsMatched() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);

  resetBoard();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to remove any event handler here.

Since you are adding a `flip` class when an element is clicked. You can use it in the delegated event like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".card:not(.flip)" , flipCard);
```

So the delegated click handler will apply to cards not having the `flip` class.

Then, you to manage when to add and remove the class. ;)